# delete a certain record from a rows in database

Tags: php, sql

Hi guys I am trying to delete only one record from a database for example:

```
 ID     Flower_type           Flower_name        Price
  1      Bouquet                 Beauty            150
  2      Basket                  Sunshine          120
```

Now i will have another table to edit the flower_types:

```
ID              Flower_type              
1                Bouquet
2                Basket
3              Flower Arrangement
```

Now if i need to edit "Bouquet" to "Bouquets" i want to delete the record with ID  "1" in the other table so the flower_type will change immediately.

I stuck where i need to delete because i can't delete flower_type record only.

This is what it tried but the query is not good. There is a way to chnage it? .. or i can update the table ?

This is the code i tried :

```
{
    $update = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id FROM tbl_flower WHERE flower_type ='$_SESSION[prevname]'");
    $update_rows = mysqli_num_rows($update);

    for($i = 0;$i < $update_rows; $i++){
        while($row = $update -> fetch_assoc()){
           $i++;
           echo $row['id']; 
           $id = $row['id'];
           $DELETE = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE flower_type FROM tbl_flower WHERE id='$id'");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have designed the database incorrectly. If you have flower_type table then in flower table the id of that flower type should be inserting. This will simplify your work. And is also the correct way of implementing

Comment: i made update query and worked .. i know it is simplier but this is my first website and you learn from mistakes.. thank you :)

Comment: you can try this  mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM tbl_flower WHERE flower_type ='$_SESSION[prevname]'");

Comment: it deletes all the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table design is goes wrong and duplicate columns. Your table should be design in this way following example:

```
Flower Table
+-----+-------------+-------+
| ID  | flower_name | price |
|-----+-------------+-------|
| 1   | Beauty      | 150   |
|-----+-------------+-------|
| 2   | Sunshine    | 120   |
+-----+-------------+-------+

Flower Type Table
+------------+----------------+
| flower_id  | flower_type_id | 
|------------+----------------+
| 1          | 1              | 
+------------+----------------+

Type Table
+-----+-------------------------+
| ID  | flower_type             |
|-----+-------------------------+
| 1   | Bouquet                 |
|-----+-------------------------+
| 2   | Basket                  |
|-----+-------------------------+
| 3   | Flower Arrangement      |
+-----+-------------------------+
```

In your case, your need to separate into a new table which is called flower type table.

The advantage to doing this way, when you update flower type name you don't bother any duplicate column you need to update in other table. Also, when you delete flower type just delete along with the Flower type table where the flower_type_id is equal to your flower type ID.

When you want to list all the flower with its type, you can use MySql join those tables.

You should learn [Database Relationship](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/table-relationships/) and [join statement](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) to design your database in practice way

Comment: Which one is better yours and the above answer ?

Comment: @Sigiii You should also study 'database normalization' before designing any more databases. Spare yourself a lot of future pain.

Comment: serverSentinel also is correct, its really depend your logic. like my suggest table it can archive one flower can have many type. but serverSentinel one only can have one type for each flower. you will know what i talking about when you have basic concept of database relationship :)

Comment: This solution works well and has other advantages.  It is required when the Flower table can be linked to multiple Types.  If you add a unique index to FlowerType it can even enforce that Flower only has 1 Type.  

It cannot enforce that a Flower has a Type.  If you fail to insert into FlowerType then you have a Flower row without a Type. If this is not desired, add Flower_type field with the not null constraint.   Very subtle difference but one that can bite you later.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is your tables are not normalized and you can do this with a simple update statement instead of delete. You have flower_type in 2 different tables but it should only be in 1.  You use joins in your select statements to bring these tables together.

I added names to your sample data for reference.

```
FlowerArrangements
 ID     Flower_name        Price    Flower_type
  1      Beauty            150      1
  2      Sunshine          120      2

ArrangementType
ID              Flower_type              
1                Bouquet
2                Basket
3              Flower Arrangement
```

Joining the 2 tables can be done like this

```
select *
from FlowerArrangements fa
join ArrangementType at
   on fa.Flower_type = at.ID
```

Now updating Bouquet to Bouquets is as easy as

```
update ArrangementType set Flower_type='Bouquets' where Flower_type = 'Bouquet'
```

All FlowerArrangements returning Bouquet before will return Bouquets when you rerun the select query.

Comment: ohhh okk !.. i will change my db :) Thanks